# If statement not working with timer

Tags: ios, if-statement, timer, swift4

When 10 seconds hit the timer. I would like the background color to be change. Right now my code is not working. Nothing is being changed when the code hits 10 seconds. I also dont think the timer is working.

```
@IBOutlet var espn: UILabel!

var TIMER = Timer()
var seconds = 0


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)




    if seconds == 10{self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
@IBAction func startTimer() {       

        TIMER = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(threeVC.clocker), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}


@objc func clocker() {
    seconds += 1
    espn.text = String( seconds)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@IBOutlet var espn: UILabel!

var TIMER = Timer()
var seconds = 0


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)        
}

@IBAction func startTimer() {

    TIMER = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(threeVC.clocker), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}


@objc func clocker() {
    seconds += 1
    espn.text = String( seconds)
    if seconds == 10{
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        print("soda")
    }
}
```

if statement should be written in `@objc func clocker()` not in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: `func clocker()` is called each time the second change, so you should implement if statement in  `func clocker()` . But `viewDidAppear` is not called after the view appeared literally.